# how do I group results based on categories?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a data visualization API where I need to use the results of `ASerializer` by their given tag in order to categorize each object into categories based on their associated tag if the object contains two tags, then it should be displayed in both . e.g

```
current output

{
   "count":117,
   "next":"http://localhost:8002/api/v1/demo/list/?page=2",
   "previous":null,
   "results":[
        {
            "_id": "T1189",
            "title": "promise",
            "tag": [
                "Demo",
                "Demo2"
            ],
            "queries": [],
        }
   ]
}


desired format 

[
    {
        "Demo": [
            {
                "_id": "T1189",
                "title": "promise",
                "tag": [
                    "Demo",
                    "Demo2"
                ],
                "queries": [],
            }
        ],
        "Demo2": [
            {
                "_id": "T1189",
                "title": "promise",
                "tag": [
                    "Demo",
                    "Demo2"
                ],
                "queries": [],
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

code

```
# serializers
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        print(value)
        return value.name

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)

class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    queries = QueriesSerializer(source='modelb_set', many=True)
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = ('_id','title', 'tag','queries',)

class QueriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'

#viewsets   
class BooksViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ASerializer
```

Comment: Using dynamic keys for dictionaries in APIs is a bad practice, and it's better to have it like:  `{"tag_name": "value", "items": []}`
Besides that, consider scaling your application and your challenges with data pagination, you shouldn't just return a list of associated objects to a list, as it can cause performance issues in the long run.
Try to rethink what you exactly wanna do.

Comment: @MohammadMoallemi they are no dynamically they are static where it contains 16 categories

Answer (score 0):

If there is an reverse relationship in your database between `Tags` and `ModelA` you might be able to do some SubQuery for it. But it looks simple enough for me to do this srot of post processing in the view layer:

```py
class BooksViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        models = ASerializer(ModelA.objects.all(), many=True).data

        return_obj = {"Demo": [], "Demo2": []}

        for model in models:
            for key in  return_obj:
                if key in model["tag"]:
                    return_obj[key].append(model)

        return JsonResponse(return_obj)
```

Comment: I got listSerializer not serializable

Comment: I missed the `.data` in `models = ASerializer(ModelA.objects.all(), many=True)`. I improved it, it should work now.